# On a smooth surface, a subsheaf of a locally free sheaf with torsion free quotient is locally free.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

I am reading D. Gieseker's [On the moduli of vector bundles on an algebraic surface](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971157). In Lemma 4.1, the author seems to use the following result

> If $0\to G_2\to G_1\to F\to0$ is an exact sequence of coherent sheaves on a smooth surface, and $F$ is torsion free, $G_1$ is locally free, then $G_2$ is locally free.

I wonder whether the above is true and where can I find a reference of such result.

Comment: It is correct. The assumption on $F$ says depth of $G_2$ is at least two and then it is locally free since the surface is smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the surface by $S$ and let $x \in S$ be any point. Then we get a short exact sequence on stalks,
$$\tag{1} 0 \to G_{2,x} \to G_{1,x} \to F_x \to 0.$$
Since $F$ is torsion-free, so is $F_x$. This means that for any element $a \in \mathcal O_{S,x}$, the map
$$F_x \to F_x, f \mapsto a \cdot f$$
is injective. In other words, $a$ is $F_x$-regular. Hence $\operatorname{depth} F_x \geq 1$. Since $G_{1}$ is locally free and $\mathcal O_{S,x}$ is regular, $\operatorname{depth} G_{1,x} = \dim \mathcal O_{S,x}$. Then from (1) we get an estimate
$$\operatorname{depth} G_{2,x} \geq \min(\operatorname{depth} G_{1,x}, \operatorname{depth} F_x + 1) = \dim \mathcal O_{S,x}.$$
Here it is crucial that $S$ is a surface, so that $\dim \mathcal O_{S,x} \leq 2 \leq \operatorname{depth} F_x + 1$.
So we see that $G_{2,x}$ is free.

Comment: I think some inequalities should be reversed, shouldn't they?

Comment: @DisplayName I believe them to be correct. The first inequality comes from the long exact sequence when applying $Hom(\kappa, -)$ and the $Ext$-characterisation of depth. The second chain of inequalities is used when evaluating the minimum.